# MLR tool to convert JSON to CSV and pad missing fields from all possible headers in json

Tags: json, csv, miller

If I have three json objects in : test.json

```json
{
  "queue": "A",
  "field1": 22,
  "field2": 2,
                 "unique_field": 0
}
{
  "queue": "B",
  "field1": 39,
  "field2": 3
}
{
  "queue": "C",
  "field1": 336,
  "field2": 5
}
```

Running MLR to convert to CSV returns two unique sets based on headers

```
./mlr --j2c cat test.json
queue,field1,field2,unique_field
A,22,2,0

queue,field1,field2
B,39,3
C,336,5
```

What I would like is for MLR to pad any missing fields with null so only 1 header is present

```
queue,field1,field2,unique_field
A,22,2,0
B,39,3,null
C,336,5,null
```

I am not sure what to try yet, as need expertise from MLR community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the [unsparsify](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.7.0/reference-verbs/index.html#unsparsify) verb:

```
./mlr --j2c unsparsify test.json
```